# Text processing to identify parts of speech

Tags: java, text, full-text-search, nlp

I've to write a program (in Java) to identify several parts of speech like nouns, adjectives, verbs etc. The program should also identify number (in numeric e.g. 10) and numbers written in plain English (ten, hundred etc) and much more. I'm not sure that what is the way forward. Is there any library available that can help? Can this be done only with regex? Or do I need to learn NLP?

Please suggest a way forward.

Comment: +1: For counteracting the negative vote given.

Comment: @Yavar I published it after a long thought and I guess it's not too specific. But even then I got negative votes.

Answer (score 2):

(1) OpenNLP

(2) LingPipe

(3) Stanford NLP

All 3 of the above (Java based) will help you out, out of the box in identifying the POS.

For numbers use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Part-of-speech (POS) tagging is a pretty standard NLP task. You could in theory write regular expressions that would POS-tag very simple sentences, you're unlikely to achieve reasonable coverage or accuracy with a regex model. You can do pretty well training a reasonably simple HMM model or a discriminative tagger on a hand-tagged training set.

But to tag a specific corpus, you don't necessarily need to learn all the details of POS tagging and roll your own - learning to use an existing library will probably suffice (e.g. NLTK or the Stanford NLP libraries).

Converting textual numeric representations to their arabic form (or vice-versa) falls under the label of 'text-normalization'. Regular expressions (or other finite-state transformations) might be more useful there, although again, you might want to look for an existing solution that meets your needs before you start from scratch.